# Why were sam and lilith going to have sex?

Tags: plot-explanation, supernatural

In the television series, Supernatural, S04E18, Why were Sam and Lilith going to have sex at the first place at all?

If Sam was going to have a contract with Lilith, then that would require just a kiss.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Supernatural Wiki](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Lilith)

> Lilith is able to make deals herself and is bound by the same rules as a Crossroads Demon in making them, however, she claims a deal with her will take a sexual act instead of a kiss, but this may simply be her preference.

As far as I remember, she explicitly tells Sam that **this** deal needs to be consummated instead of the usual *seal-the-deal* kiss. But then again, I think she was just toying with the handsome man.